# fatal error: BlynkSimpleEsp32.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, arduino, iot, esp32, blynk

I just want to know if I'm doing something wrong since I'm new to all this concepts.
If there is anything else that you'll like me to add just let me know.

[image: here is screenshot of error]

```
#include <BlynkSimpleEsp32.h>
```

when I try to verify my code it says **fatal error: BlynkSimpleEsp32.h: No such file or directory
Multiple libraries were found for "WiFi.h"
compilation terminated.**

Comment: If it says no such file or directory believe your IDE. Perhaps the required library is not installed in Arduino ide.

Comment: Maybe you need to do this: [https://community.blynk.cc/t/include-blynksimpleesp32/44069](https://community.blynk.cc/t/include-blynksimpleesp32/44069)

Comment: Yeah! you're right I need to install Blynk Library.

Comment: if anyone facing this problem just goes to Sketch in IDE then Include Library> Manage Libraries and search for Blynk and just install it :)